# Get language of a website using simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, detect, lang

I am building a search engine and webcrawler using PHP, and i would like to detect the language of a website, how would i detect the language of a page by:

1. Checking the URL for https://twitter.com/?lang=jap
   if that is not set then i would like to:
2. Check the URL https://www.google.co.jp/

if i still can't find anything then i would to set default to English

the code i have so far for scraping pages is:

```
function crawl($url){
            $html = file_get_html($url);
            if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
                $weblinks[]=$url;
                foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
                    global $weblinks;
                    $link = $element->href;
                    $base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
                    if(substr($link,0,7)=="http://"){
                        $link = $link;
                    }else if(substr($link,0,8)=="https://"){
                        $link = $link;
                    }else if(substr($link,0,2)=="//"){
                        $link = substr($link, 2);
                    }else if(substr($link,0,1)=="#"){
                        $link = $html;
                    }else if(substr($link,0,7)=="mailto:"){
                        $link = "";
                    }else if(substr($link,0,11)=="javascript:"){
                        $link = "";
                    }else{
                        if(substr($link, 0, 1) != "/"){
                            $link = $base_url."/".$link;
                        }else{
                            $link = $base_url . $link;
                        }
                    }
                    if(substr($link, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($link, 0, 8) != "https://" && $link != ""){
                        if(substr($url, 0, 8) == "https://"){
                            $link = "https://".$link;
                        }else{
                            $link = "http://".$link;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!in_array($link, $weblinks)){
                        $weblinks[]=$link;
                    }
                }
                $html->clear();
            }else{

            }
        }
        function info($weblinks){
            foreach($weblinks as $link) {
                $linkhtml = file_get_html("$link");
                if($linkhtml && is_object($linkhtml) && isset($linkhtml->nodes)){

                    $titleraw = $linkhtml->find('title',0);
                    $title = $titleraw->innertext;
                    $des = $linkhtml->find("meta[name='description']",0)->content;


//detect language here

                    echo "<tr><td>".$title."</td><td>".$link."</td><td>".$des."</td></tr>";
                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT into web once");
                    $title = "";
                    $des = "";
                    $linkhtml->clear();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your post to ask a question, or a moderator will soon close the post

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I'm sorry, i thought i asked a straight forward question, but i slightly changed it to make it a more noticeable question :)

Comment: I would also recommend adding in what works/ doesn't work with your current code so people know what to look for when reading it :)

Comment: @ChristopherShroba The entire code there works, i just don't know how to go about detecting it without making my code unnecessarily long or missing languages/TLD's. I did a search on google and couldn't find anything that would help me with this. 

I just added in my code so that people could see how it's set up and how i'm parsing the urls and passing them around.

Comment: Possibly this page http://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html#language will help you with a starting place.

Answer (score 1):

To get the language from `?lang=`:

```
$url = 'www.domain.org?lang=IT';
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$lang = parse_str($url_parts['lang']);
```

You should then validate this with a switch/case statement and a list of languages that you support, like this:

```
switch ($lang) {
case 'EN':
//language is English
break;
case 'IT':
//language is Italian
break;
case 'FR':
//language is French
break;
default:
//?lang query was empty, or contained an unsupported language
$lang = FALSE;
} //end switch
```

After that, you can use this logic to determine whether you need to check the URL for the language:

```
if ($lang == FALSE) {
//code to determine language from TLD
}
```

Hopefully this will help get you started, although this is a big can of worms you're opening up. There are other things you need to check in order to be certain of the language of a website in addition to what you've mentioned. One of them is the language meta tag, which is like this: `<meta name="language" content="english">` and goes in the head of the webpage, though not all websites use it.

Some multilingual websites, like mine, use a subdomain like `http://it.website.com` or `http://fr.website.com`

Others use query strings that are different from `?lang=`. So you'll need to do a significant amount of research to cover all your bases.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i was hoping for a cleaner way, but i guess with such a big project, there's really no way of "cleanly" doing so.