# How to determine the language of a website

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a url of a website and need to find out which language the website uses (whether it's spanish, french, italian, etc).

The site's top level domain is *.com*, and this doesn't help at all. I cannot simply check if the string contains '.de', '.fr', or any other country codes.

I was trying to get the `lang` attribute of the `html` tag, but there are many websites that don't have it. Also I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058638/get-language-of-a-website-using-simple-html-dom) that I can check the meta tag, which would look like this:

```
<meta name="language" content="english">
```

But again, not all websites use this tag.

Do you know any other ways to determine a website's language?

Thanks.

Comment: Only by profiling the text. Not a trivial thing to do on your own.

Comment: There is no easy way to determine the language of a website, short of using some kind of language detection algorithm. There may be some  SaaS provider out there that specializes in this; Google is your friend.

Comment: There is no single, reliable method. You have to apply a heuristic, so make several tests for several markers and then compute a probability for the languages.

Comment: OK, got it. I'll just stick with meta tag and lang attribute for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly many developers don't think that adding a language metainfo to their web page is something useful. Also it might be that the page has multiple languages on it which - as far as I know - forces the usage of the `<div>` parameter `lang` or other such things. Here are some pointers that might help you:

1. Check for the `<meta name="language" content="...">` tag
2. Check inside `<div>`s and look if those contain `lang` parameter
3. Check the menus (if any) - these usually contain much, much less text than the main body of the page
4. Look for further smaller chunks of HTML data that you can parse easily and that can give you more information about the language(s) the page uses
5. Finally start heuristically analyzing the big text chunks

It's actually really sad how things currently are because providing such information is not that difficult and doesn't require much extra time invested into doing it but the pros are definitely there especially when it comes to search engines and most importantly - improving the accessibility for people who have various disabilities.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame that many developers neglect the language meta data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like google translate, microsoft translate or languagelayer for language text detection.

I have gone through these apis docs and limits and prices and chose languagelayer personnaly as it is the cheapest and seeems easier to use.